# How to close database connection when cancel Pentaho Table input Preview?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I recently upgraded Pentaho from version 6.1 to version 9.1 CE. And I encountered a difference in behavior that gives me difficulties. When I use the "Preview" in the Table Input step with a long-running query and without waiting for the result I cancel this Preview using the Cancel button, the query continues to hang on the database. At the same time, in version 6.1, with similar actions, the connection on the Database was closed. Tell me, please, what could be the matter? What settings can be changed in version 9.1 to get the desired effect (closing the connection on the database MS SQL Server Native JDBC when canceling Previews)?

[image: preview cancel]